# Bootstrap and jQuery - which do I upgrade first

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, upgrade

I'm currently using Bootstrap 2.0.0, jQuery 1.7.1 and jQueryui-1.8.16. Trying to figure out if I can upgrade jQuery first without anything in Bootstrap breaking. Or do they have to be upgraded in tandem? Where can I find out what's the highest version of jQuery that is supported by Bootstrap 2.0.0.

Thank you!

Comment: jQuery library first but it's not simple in case if you have custom scripts. and jQuery 2.1.0 Support Bootstrap 2.3.2

Comment: You are likely able to update to the latest jQuery without breaking Bootstrap 2, but I cannot find any minimum/maximum jquery requirements on the Bootstrap site. I'd go `1) jQuery 2) jQueryUi (replace with bootstrap components if possible) 3) Bootstrap` But I'd try and do them all within a short period of time. Then test test test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jump from jQuery 1.7 to 1.9.1 isn't breaking so you can update that without consequence. The jump from Bootstrap 2 to Bootstrap 3 is massively breaking and will more likely than not require a complete rebuild as the grid system works differently in Bootstrap 3 (accounts for device size).

At this point you're better off waiting a couple months for Bootstrap 4. In the meantime you can certainly bump jQuery to 1.9.1 or jQuery 2 if you don't need to worry about supporting old version of IE.